# How to specialize template template parameter for std::vector in C++

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I need a specialization of this code:

```
template < class T, class Alloc, template <class, class> class VECTOR >
void function(const VECTOR<T, Alloc> &argument);
```

for a template std::vector. For now, it works with any 2-argument template ("class VECTOR") argument.

In other words:

```
// A, B -- any unpredictable types

function< std::vector <A, B> > (arg);            // specialization
function< Some2ArgsTemplate <A, B> > (arg);      // general
function< SomeOther2ArgsTemplate <A, B> > (arg); // general
```

Is it possible to implement that with no knowledge about A and B? Any C++11/C++14 ideas are OK.

Comment: What's wrong with `template <class T, class Alloc> void function (const std::vector<T, Alloc>& argument);` and calling with deduction (`function(arg)`)?

Answer (score 4):

Don't specialize, overload:

```
template < class T, class Alloc>
void function(const std::vector<T, Alloc> &argument);
```

This will be preferred in you pass in a `std::vector` as opposed to any other 2-type class template (e.g. `std::list`). And it will be preferred in a consistent, easy-to-reason about way. Also, you can't partially specialize function templates anyway.

Explicit function template specialization is... [problematic](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm). The order that you write your specializations could be significant!

---

Note that this syntax isn't correct:

```
function< Some2ArgsTemplate <A, B> > (arg);
```

Explicitly specified template arguments go left-to-right. So here you're specifying `T` to be `Some2ArgsTemplate <A, B>`... which probably prevents deduction from succeeding. You shouldn't need to explicitly specify anything:

```
Some2ArgTemplate<A, B> arg = ...;
function(arg); // deduce T=A, Alloc=B, VECTOR=Some2ArgTemplate
```